# How to skip the next two iterations in for loop using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

In a for loop, let's assume it contains 100 iterations, and what I need is, i need to print the first element and skip the next two element, and then need to prit the fourth element.. for example,

```
0 #should print 
1 #should skip
2 #should skip
3 #should print 
4 #should skip
5 #should skip
6 #should print
.
. like wise
```

I tried some existing skipping solutions out this platform, but didn't fit for my problem.
I know the continue statement allows you to skip over the current iteration, but I can't figure out how to **skip the next two iterations**. Ttried some itertool fuctions also.

Comment: Share your actual code, so we can see on what you're iterating

Comment: `range()` can take a step parameter that lets you control "skipping": https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range

Comment: It seems as though perhaps you are a beginning programmer.  In general, the `while` construct is much more powerful than `for`.  You might want to consider how you could make a `while| loop that accomplished this.

Comment: @azro , please go thru this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/74337703/9549067

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you iterate on your own `range`, generate one over three elements

```
values = ["dog0", "dog1", "dog2", "dog3", "dog4", "dog5", "dog6"]
for i in range(0, 8, 3):
    print(i, values[i])
```

If you iterate over an iterable of values, use `enumerate` to filter

```
values = ["dog0", "dog1", "dog2", "dog3", "dog4", "dog5", "dog6"]
for i, value in enumerate(values):
    if i % 3 != 0:
        continue
    print(i, value)
```

Comment: The problem is explained here, please go thru it  https://stackoverflow.com/q/74337703/9549067

Comment: @Ammar_Fahmy my second code gives you the EXACT solution,  just do `for i, item in enumerate(items)`

Comment: Yes of Course, Implemented this too

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach would be using `enumerate` and mod (`%`).

```
nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

for index, num in enumerate(nums):
    print(num) if index % 3 == 0 else None
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a range you can use the optional step argument `range(start, stop, step)`

```
for k in range(start, stop, 3): print(k)
```

or

```
for k in range(len(my_data), step=3): print(k)
```

If it's a list you can use list slicing
where once again the optional arguments for slicing is start, stop and step!

```
for k in my_array[::3]: print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `enumerate` as others have mentioned. Your problem basically consists in printing all positions `[i]` that are multipes of `3`. You can use `i%3` to detect when the iteration counter `i` is not a multiple of 3:

```
for i,x in enumerate(???):
    if i%3: continue
    print(x)
```

`enumerate` also works when you have an iterator `f` of unkown size (like when you read a file, etc.)

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
skip_count = 2  # how many to skip
counter = skip_count

for num in arr:
    if counter == skip_count:
        counter = 0
        print(num)
    else:
        counter += 1
```

Alternatively, this will work too

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for index in range(0, len(arr), 3):
    print(arr[index])
```