# How to skip some iterations inside bs4 tags?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrap data (thumbnail image link) from [this](https://robloxden.com/item-codes) site.
The problem is, when it's getting the data it takes three

tags, but the onle first tag has that thumbnail link, other two are not important. So, I need to skip those two tags and move to the fourth

tag. For example,

```
0 <li> #contains the thumbnail link
1 <li> #should skip
2 <li> #should skip
3 <li> #contains the thumbnail link
4 <li> #should skip
5 <li> #should skip
6 <li> #contains the thumbnail link
```

like wise.

Here is my code,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import openpyxl

try:
    
    response = requests.get("https://robloxden.com/item-codes")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find('ul', class_="masonry masonry--5 item-codes__container").find_all("li")
 
    for item in items:
        # product's icon link
        item_link = item.find('div', class_="image-card__graphic image-card__graphic--border-bottom").img
        item_link = item_link['data-src']

        print(item_link)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

(just copy and run the above script, can explore the problem)
this works only for first tag, and terminated with `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'img'` this error, which means the second `<li>` tag does not contain the `<img>` tag. So need to skip the second and thrid `<li>` tags, the foruth `<li>` tag contains that `<img>` data.
As bigginer to learn scrapping, please guide me to solve this problem.

Comment: The answer given is exactly what you need. OR there is something more that you don't tell us

Comment: @azro , Yes I have completed my code with the solution provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `enumerate` and skip every 2 items and only continue (not to be confused with `continue`) with code for every 3rd item.

```py
for index, item in enumerate(items):
    if index % 3 != 0:
        continue
    
    ...
```

If the issue is that `.find` returns `None` at some point you can use a `try/except`:

```py
for item in items:
    try:
        ...
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```